# Change label input on click and then back to original when a different image clicked?

Tags: css, button, checkbox, input, label

So i'm using a checkbox hack in order to change 3 buttons on click, when someone clicks one it changes to a selected button image, then someone clicks on another button it changes the other button back to the original image and the new other clicked button goes to select. The problem is I can't figure out how to have 3 different selected states. One for each color. Right now it just uses the greenbtn-selected obviously, how would I add more than one so that each button had it's own selected state?

Also for some reason content:url isn't working on Firefox? Is there another way to do it, I tried background:url and that doesn't work in Chrome! ugh.

Thanks so much!!!

The selected button images..

```
http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/greenbtn-select.png
http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/bluebtn-select.png
http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/orangebtn-select.png
```

The Buttons..

```
<label>
<input id="ctl00_generalContentPlaceHolder_rbPackage1" type="radio" value="rbPackage1" name="ctl00$generalContentPlaceHolder$product">
<img src="http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/greenbtn-select.png">
</label>

<label>
<input id="ctl00_generalContentPlaceHolder_rbPackage1" type="radio" value="rbPackage1" name="ctl00$generalContentPlaceHolder$product">
<img src="http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/orangebtn-select.png">
</label>

<label>
<input id="ctl00_generalContentPlaceHolder_rbPackage1" type="radio" value="rbPackage1" name="ctl00$generalContentPlaceHolder$product">
<img src="http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/bluebtn-select.png">
</label>
```

The CSS...

```
label > input + img {
    cursor: pointer;
}
label > input {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 130px;
}
label > input:checked + img {
    content: url("http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/orangebtn-selected.png");
}
```

```js
label > input + img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
label > input {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 130px;
}
label > input: checked + img {
  content: url("http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/orangebtn-selected.png");
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input id="ctl00_generalContentPlaceHolder_rbPackage1" type="radio" value="rbPackage1" name="ctl00$generalContentPlaceHolder$product">
  <img src="http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/greenbtn-select.png">
</label>

<label>
  <input id="ctl00_generalContentPlaceHolder_rbPackage1" type="radio" value="rbPackage1" name="ctl00$generalContentPlaceHolder$product">
  <img src="http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/orangebtn-select.png">
</label>

<label>
  <input id="ctl00_generalContentPlaceHolder_rbPackage1" type="radio" value="rbPackage1" name="ctl00$generalContentPlaceHolder$product">
  <img src="http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/bluebtn-select.png">
</label>
```

Comment: What 'states' do you want the buttons to have, exactly? Incidentally, the code you've posted doesn't seem to produce any noticeable changes in the appearance of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use `image` use a `<div>` or `span`

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vjp9f7L2/4/)

give a background image and use `pseudo` before changing the image

html

```
<label>
    <input id="ctl00_generalContentPlaceHolder_rbPackage1" type="radio" value="rbPackage1" name="ctl00$generalContentPlaceHolder$product">
    <span class="check-green"></span>
</label>
```

css

```
.check-green {
    background:url(http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/greenbtn-select.png);
    width:124px;
    height:30px;
}

label > input:checked + span:before {
    content: url("http://www.morecleanenergy.com/graphics/mass/images/orangebtn-selected.png");
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: actually I just realized it's still doing the same thing. It only changes to the orange selected button after click. :( I need the blue to change to bluebtn-selected, orange to orangebtn-selected and green to greenbtn-selected.

Comment: I figured it out, just had to add in the span classes

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vjp9f7L2/5/  change class for each span `span.check-blue:before`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript and register a click event for each of the buttons. Something like this;

Jquery

```
$('button1').click(function(){
   //do necessary changes
});
```